# angular ui-grid : how to apply filter on group-headers?

Tags: html, angularjs, ui-grid

when applying filter on group-headers in ui-grid , they disappear . i have the same problem with column-footer when we have it in result of a grouping operation (when footer aggregate function is defined without grouping it is shown correctly with applied filter ).

```
col.cellTemplate='<div>{{COL_FIELD | currency:"":0}} </div>';
```

i have to change it to bellow to get it work:

```
col.cellTemplate= 
'<div ng-if="!row.groupHeader">{{COL_FIELD | currency:"":0}} </div>'    
+'<div ng-if="row.groupHeader" >{{COL_FIELD }}</div>'
```

but it is not what i really need ;

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by default adds a label to the header. This causes issues with the cell filters. You have two options.

1. Remove labels from the group headers. This can be easily achieved by using a [customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.treeBase.api:ColumnDef). Add the below code to the columnDefs of the required columns.

> customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: function( aggregation ){
>   aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value; }

After adding this your cellFilter property will work on the group headers.

2. Modify your filters to analyse and work with the group labels.